# Doesn't check user authorization in th: each loop Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring-security, authorization, thymeleaf

There are several organizational units, each with a custom role. On the page, after authorization, you need to display a button intended only for this role (department). This code works:

```
<div>
  <a th:sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_DEP-1')" href="/userPage/department1" type="button">DEP-1</a>
  <a th:sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_DEP-2')" href="/userPage/department2" type="button">DEP-2</a>
  <a th:sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_DEP-3')" href="/userPage/department3" type="button">DEP-3</a>
  <a th:sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_DEP-4')" href="/userPage/department4" type="button">DEP-4</a>
</div>
```

but I think it will not be correct to write all subdivisions manually, because more units may be added in the future. I decided to do it through the th: each Thymeleaf loop:

```
<div th:each="d : ${departments}">
   <a th:sec:authorize="hasRole('+${d.role.name}+')" href="/userPage/department" type="button" th:text="${d.shortName}"></a>
</div>
```

but unfortunately this does not work, the buttons are not displayed. Role names are displayed correctly. The relationship between the department and role tables is 1:1. I can’t understand why it doesn’t work.
It may be necessary to have a special syntax inside this function:

> "hasRole('+${d.role.name}+')"

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [preprocessing](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing):

```
<div th:each="d : ${departments}">
   <a sec:authorize="hasRole(' + __${d.role.name}__ +')" href="/userPage/department" type="button" th:text="${d.shortName}"></a>
</div>
```